# CKEditor 4: Use links to anchors to navigate inside the editor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Is it possible to have a link-list with links to anchors (id's) outside the editor and when I click on a link the editor text should scroll to the given anchor id.

I tried to create a example with jsfiddle but I'm not able to embed the editor, when I get it I will post a example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [`CKEDITOR.dom.element.scrollIntoView()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-scrollIntoView) should do the trick:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditor.document.getById( 'someId' ).scrollIntoView();
```

Attach it to any element of your link-list, either with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or jQuery [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function.